# What to do about invalid "duplicate"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859340/dividing-just-by-subtracting-and-finding-the-remainder-without-using-the-divisi) was closed as a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369414/write-a-program-to-find-remainder-of-dividing-two-numbers-without-using-opera).

But the first is asking how to do shift-subtract division while the second wants to know how to compute a remainder without using `%`.  How can the first possibly be a duplicate of the second?

Comment: Though the concepts in the questions are related, you are right. The only thing you can do is nominate it for reopening. I cast a re-open vote and maybe others here can too. As you noted in the comments, I would be surprised if there wasn't a duplicate of that question somewhere on SO, but you are right, that question is not a valid duplicate.

Comment: Ah, but my question isn't a dupe since it about two entirely different questions! ;)

Comment: (And, completely seriously, the other isn't a dupe, since it's about "flagging" a question which hasn't been closed.)